# Sharepoint FBA 2010 : Custom Application Page (Sign-in Page) redirection issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, forms-authentication, fba

I have configured FBA on Sharepoint 2010 site. And its working fine when I use the OOTB login page which is available at `_form/default.aspx`.

Now I have created my own `Login.aspx` page and configured the web application to get redirected to this custom page. This page I have kept it at `Layouts/CustomFBA/Login.aspx` location under 14 Hive. I followed [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/22/writing-a-custom-forms-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010-part-2.aspx) to create and configure the login page.

I have included a user sign in page link at the bottom of this login page which is another application page.

I have updated the web.config of the web application to allow users to reach to the user sign-in page without getting authenticated or redirected to login page again. Ideally this should work, but somehow whenever I click that link I am being redirected back to the login page. I will really appreciate if somebody can help me in this regard

==========================================================

As I have mentioned earlier,the custom login page is working perfectly fine. But, I have link on the login page which take the users to a sign-in(UserSignin.aspx) page which is also kept in the /_layouts/CustomFBA/ folder. The problem is when I click the link, I am coming back to the Login page again.
As per some of the blog which I read, they have mentioned to allow user to view such page which should not ask for any authentication, we have to include the tag (mentioned by djeeg) in web.config of the web application. So I have done that as well.

But this is also not resolving the problem. I am still coming back to Login.aspx page when I click that "Sign-in" link on the Custom Login Page. I hope I have made my problem clear here.

Thanks & Regards,
Paddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SharePoint application pages added in Visual Studio inherit from the `LayoutsPageBase` class ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.layoutspagebase.aspx): *represents an application page to which **access can be limited to users that possess certain rights***).

Change the base class of the `UserSignin.aspx` page to `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.unsecuredlayoutspagebase.aspx): *represents the base class for application pages that **explicitly do not require the user to have any permissions**, such as the access denied page*).

Comment: Check I have added some more inputs in my original question.

Comment: Thanks Marek I will try this and let you know if this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your web.config

```
<location path="_layouts/CustomFBA/Login.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

That should then allow anonymous access to your custom login page

Comment: Check I have added some more inputs in my original question.